# Differentiate between RX and TX messages in a CAN DBC

Tags: can-bus

I want to differentiate between rx and tx CAN-messages from a DBC but can't find any difference, when I open it with notebook. As anyone a idea if they can be identified in a DBC?

Comment: What exactly is a "RX" and "TX" message and in what context?

Comment: You have RX and TX Messages. RX-receive and TX-transmit. If got a small CAN Network and want to print the messages to a excel, so you can better work with them. This part works, but now I want to differentiate between rx and tx so you can easily work an one or another.

Comment: I know in  DBC you usually can differentiate between them, but I saw someone using Vector marking the TX messages and wondered if this information is in a Vector DBC, maybe

Comment: "You have RX and TX Messages" There is no such thing in a generic CAN context. There are things like TPDO and RPDO per node in higher layer CANopen and similar, but not on the data link layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DBC Format is described [here](http://socialledge.com/sjsu/index.php/DBC_Format#CAN_RX) and [here](https://github.com/stefanhoelzl/CANpy/blob/master/docs/DBC_Specification.md).

The sender is specified on the same line as the message definition like so:

```
BO_ <CAN-ID> <MessageName>: <MessageLength> <SendingNode>
```

While the receiver is specified on the signal line:

```
SG_ <SignalName> [M|m<MultiplexerIdentifier>] : <StartBit>|<Length>@<Endianness><Signed> (<Factor>,<Offset>) [<Min>|<Max>] "[Unit]" [ReceivingNodes]
```

So for the following definition, `IO` is the sending node while `DBG` is the receiving node (in other word this is a Tx-Message for `IO` and an Rx-Message for `DBG`):

```
BO_ 500 IO_DEBUG: 4 IO
 SG_ IO_DEBUG_test_unsigned : 0|8@1+ (1,0) [0|0] "" DBG
```